# JavaScript MV* framework for a mobile app with old non-RESTful backend

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, design-patterns, backbone.js

I've just joined a team which is creating a mobile web app (not native) for a web site with an old non-RESTful PHP backend. At the moment the app is pretty basic and everything is done using jQuery and DOM manipulation, but we start having spaghetti code here and there.

The app is used for searching, viewing and updating a large database of articles. Typical features like user login and settings are present.

We'd like to rewrite what we have using a light-weight framework which wouldn't get in our way and allow us to communicate easily with the old backend without modifying it (which we now do using `jQuery.ajax()`).

The most popular choice seems to be Backbone.js, but by default it expects a RESTful backend. I've read in the docs that we could get around it by overriding the `sync()` function. Is this the way to go?

I know that there are [a lot of other frameworks out there](http://addyosmani.github.com/todomvc/). Is any of them more suitable in this case?

Comment: Overriding `sync` (globally, per-model, or per-collection) would probably be the way to go with Backbone. Then you can back out your `sync`s if/when you RESTify your server-side code.

Answer (score 1):

> The most popular choice seems to be Backbone.js, but by default it expects a RESTful backend. I've read in the docs that we could get around it by overriding the sync() function. Is this the way to go?

It's not that hard to override `Backbone.sync()` and you can write your own wrapper to work with just about any style API that you can communicate with via AJAX. So I'd say yes, that's a decent way to go.